# Is it possible to redirect console output to a log file in IntelliJ like Eclipse?

Tags: logging, intellij-idea

In Eclipse it's possible to redirect console output to a log file using the method outlined [here](http://itnow.blogspot.com/2006/09/redirecting-eclipse-console-output-to.html).

Is there a similar feature in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: It's not looking good, is it? If this can't be done then since moving from Eclipse this is the only thing I've found that IntelliJ can't do that Eclipse can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure IntelliJ to print the standard output in the console window but also save it to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121721/configure-intellij-to-print-the-standard-output-in-the-console-window-but-also-s)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**UPDATE**: this feature is [available in IDEA 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121721/configure-intellij-to-print-the-standard-output-in-the-console-window-but-also-s/8122275#8122275).

Not possible in IDEA at the moment, I've submitted a [new feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-64394). Feel free to vote.

A workaround could be implemented using **wrapper class** with main() method which will redirect **stdout** and **stderr** to files and then run the main class of your application.

Comment: Just voted. Good suggestion with wrapper class, unfortunately that's not viable on our current project so this new feature would be great!

Comment: Unfortunately that feature doesn't solve the problem - it captures both `stdout` and `stderr`, so if you want to see diagnostic messages in IDEA and put the program's output data in a file, you're out of luck I guess.

Comment: Also, it still shows everything in the console window.  It's really just a shortcut for copy-paste from that window to a file.

Answer (score 30):

In more recent versions of IntelliJ this is possible. Go to the "Logs" tab of a run configuration. There is a "Save console output to file option".

I'm on IntelliJ 13.1.3 but I think this feature has been around for a while.

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work for Gradle tasks in IntelliJ 2016 I have no tabs for "Logs" I will keep searching but thanks for excellent answer +1

Comment: It seems to always overwrite the log file, instead of appending.

Comment: Yes, this feature has been around for as long as I can remember. Probably goes back to early 2000s

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for a tomcat run configuration

Comment: followed the instructions, but the file does not get created or written to

Answer (score 7):

Considering the scenario, where you want to capture the log obtained on console via  `System.out.println("log info")` , you could import the following classes :

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
```

and set the output stream to a file like this:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("log_file.txt")));
```

This will redirect all the text to the file named log_file.txt
. You could also go through this 
 [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_setout.htm). Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 5):

Possible redirect console output to a log file.
Run -> Edit Configurations . To see Run/Debug Configurations window
Then go tab : Logs, check in "Save console output to file:" and fill to path file (example D:\logtoFile.txt)
Reference here : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/setting-log-options.html

Comment: followed the instructions, but the file does not get created or written to

Answer (score 1):

*IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)*, follow the steps:

- Run/Debug Configurations dialog: where you boot up your application
- Modify options: a scrolldown bar hard to locate
- Logs: scroll down, and there is a section for logs
- Save console output to file

Comment: followed the instructions, but the file does not get created or written to