# Configure IntelliJ to print the standard output in the console window but also save it to file

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I configure IntelliJ to capture the standard output of the application to a file, but still display it in the standard console window?

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736020/is-it-possible-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-log-file-in-intellij-like-eclipse

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This feature is available starting from IntelliJ IDEA 11:

[image: save log]

Comment: That's not actually capturing `stdout` (`System.out` in java), it's capturing everything that appears in the console, including `stderr`.

Answer (score 8):

This feature does work in IDEA 14.1.1. Also in Run/Debug configuration.

[image]

The writing occurs after the run finishes.

Comment: Don't know the older versions but in 2016.1.3, it flushes data right out

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 this no longer works.

P.S. If your motivation is because you can't scroll back to the output start you can increase how many lines you can scroll backwards.

[Screenshot of scrollback buffer size setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOTee.png).