# Skip content when logging with Intellij

Tags: logging, intellij-idea

I want to log console output to a file with IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121721/configure-intellij-to-print-the-standard-output-in-the-console-window-but-also-s/8122275#8122275), however, what I need is the log file to log multiple runs, what happens instead is that the last run overwrites the log file.

According to [the official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-log-options.html), I should get the continuous logging by checking the "Skip Content" checkbox in the "Run/Debug Configurations", but I'm still getting only the last run in the log.

Am I doing this right? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned option is for log files that are read during run session. It's not possible to append output to file. Please vote for the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136279