# Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

When I run the following test, it throws "Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext". The possible problem is that I use `TestSuiteBase` and Streaming Spark Context. At the line `val gridEvalsRDD = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(gridEvals)` I need to use `SparkContext` that I access via `ssc.sparkContext` and this is where I have the problem (see the warning and error messages below)

```
class StreamingTest extends TestSuiteBase with BeforeAndAfter {

test("Test 1") {
//...
    val gridEvals = for (initialWeights <- gridParams("initialWeights");
                         stepSize <- gridParams("stepSize");
                         numIterations <- gridParams("numIterations")) yield {
      val lr = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
        .setInitialWeights(initialWeights.asInstanceOf[Vector])
        .setStepSize(stepSize.asInstanceOf[Double])
        .setNumIterations(numIterations.asInstanceOf[Int])

      ssc = setupStreams(inputData, (inputDStream: DStream[LabeledPoint]) => {
        lr.trainOn(inputDStream)
        lr.predictOnValues(inputDStream.map(x => (x.label, x.features)))
      })

      val output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]] = runStreams(ssc, numBatches, numBatches)
      val cvRMSE = calculateRMSE(output, nPoints)
      println(s"RMSE = $cvRMSE")
      (initialWeights, stepSize, numIterations, cvRMSE)

    }

     val gridEvalsRDD = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(gridEvals)

}

}
```

> 16/04/27 10:40:17 WARN StreamingContext: StreamingContext has already
>   been stopped 16/04/27 10:40:17 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already
>   stopped.
>
> Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext

UPDATE:

This is the base class `TestSuiteBase`:

```
trait TestSuiteBase extends SparkFunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with Logging {

  // Name of the framework for Spark context
  def framework: String = this.getClass.getSimpleName

  // Master for Spark context
  def master: String = "local[2]"

  // Batch duration
  def batchDuration: Duration = Seconds(1)

  // Directory where the checkpoint data will be saved
  lazy val checkpointDir: String = {
    val dir = Utils.createTempDir()
    logDebug(s"checkpointDir: $dir")
    dir.toString
  }

  // Number of partitions of the input parallel collections created for testing
  def numInputPartitions: Int = 2

  // Maximum time to wait before the test times out
  def maxWaitTimeMillis: Int = 10000

  // Whether to use manual clock or not
  def useManualClock: Boolean = true

  // Whether to actually wait in real time before changing manual clock
  def actuallyWait: Boolean = false

  // A SparkConf to use in tests. Can be modified before calling setupStreams to configure things.
  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster(master)
    .setAppName(framework)

  // Timeout for use in ScalaTest `eventually` blocks
  val eventuallyTimeout: PatienceConfiguration.Timeout = timeout(Span(10, ScalaTestSeconds))

  // Default before function for any streaming test suite. Override this
  // if you want to add your stuff to "before" (i.e., don't call before { } )
  def beforeFunction() {
    if (useManualClock) {
      logInfo("Using manual clock")
      conf.set("spark.streaming.clock", "org.apache.spark.util.ManualClock")
    } else {
      logInfo("Using real clock")
      conf.set("spark.streaming.clock", "org.apache.spark.util.SystemClock")
    }
  }

  // Default after function for any streaming test suite. Override this
  // if you want to add your stuff to "after" (i.e., don't call after { } )
  def afterFunction() {
    System.clearProperty("spark.streaming.clock")
  }

  before(beforeFunction)
  after(afterFunction)

  /**
   * Run a block of code with the given StreamingContext and automatically
   * stop the context when the block completes or when an exception is thrown.
   */
  def withStreamingContext[R](ssc: StreamingContext)(block: StreamingContext => R): R = {
    try {
      block(ssc)
    } finally {
      try {
        ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true)
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          logError("Error stopping StreamingContext", e)
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Run a block of code with the given TestServer and automatically
   * stop the server when the block completes or when an exception is thrown.
   */
  def withTestServer[R](testServer: TestServer)(block: TestServer => R): R = {
    try {
      block(testServer)
    } finally {
      try {
        testServer.stop()
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          logError("Error stopping TestServer", e)
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Set up required DStreams to test the DStream operation using the two sequences
   * of input collections.
   */
  def setupStreams[U: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](
      input: Seq[Seq[U]],
      operation: DStream[U] => DStream[V],
      numPartitions: Int = numInputPartitions
    ): StreamingContext = {
    // Create StreamingContext
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, batchDuration)
    if (checkpointDir != null) {
      ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
    }

    // Setup the stream computation
    val inputStream = new TestInputStream(ssc, input, numPartitions)
    val operatedStream = operation(inputStream)
    val outputStream = new TestOutputStreamWithPartitions(operatedStream,
      new ArrayBuffer[Seq[Seq[V]]] with SynchronizedBuffer[Seq[Seq[V]]])
    outputStream.register()
    ssc
  }

  /**
   * Set up required DStreams to test the binary operation using the sequence
   * of input collections.
   */
  def setupStreams[U: ClassTag, V: ClassTag, W: ClassTag](
      input1: Seq[Seq[U]],
      input2: Seq[Seq[V]],
      operation: (DStream[U], DStream[V]) => DStream[W]
    ): StreamingContext = {
    // Create StreamingContext
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, batchDuration)
    if (checkpointDir != null) {
      ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
    }

    // Setup the stream computation
    val inputStream1 = new TestInputStream(ssc, input1, numInputPartitions)
    val inputStream2 = new TestInputStream(ssc, input2, numInputPartitions)
    val operatedStream = operation(inputStream1, inputStream2)
    val outputStream = new TestOutputStreamWithPartitions(operatedStream,
      new ArrayBuffer[Seq[Seq[W]]] with SynchronizedBuffer[Seq[Seq[W]]])
    outputStream.register()
    ssc
  }

  /**
   * Runs the streams set up in `ssc` on manual clock for `numBatches` batches and
   * returns the collected output. It will wait until `numExpectedOutput` number of
   * output data has been collected or timeout (set by `maxWaitTimeMillis`) is reached.
   *
   * Returns a sequence of items for each RDD.
   */
  def runStreams[V: ClassTag](
      ssc: StreamingContext,
      numBatches: Int,
      numExpectedOutput: Int
    ): Seq[Seq[V]] = {
    // Flatten each RDD into a single Seq
    runStreamsWithPartitions(ssc, numBatches, numExpectedOutput).map(_.flatten.toSeq)
  }

  /**
   * Runs the streams set up in `ssc` on manual clock for `numBatches` batches and
   * returns the collected output. It will wait until `numExpectedOutput` number of
   * output data has been collected or timeout (set by `maxWaitTimeMillis`) is reached.
   *
   * Returns a sequence of RDD's. Each RDD is represented as several sequences of items, each
   * representing one partition.
   */
  def runStreamsWithPartitions[V: ClassTag](
      ssc: StreamingContext,
      numBatches: Int,
      numExpectedOutput: Int
    ): Seq[Seq[Seq[V]]] = {
    assert(numBatches > 0, "Number of batches to run stream computation is zero")
    assert(numExpectedOutput > 0, "Number of expected outputs after " + numBatches + " is zero")
    logInfo("numBatches = " + numBatches + ", numExpectedOutput = " + numExpectedOutput)

    // Get the output buffer
    val outputStream = ssc.graph.getOutputStreams.
      filter(_.isInstanceOf[TestOutputStreamWithPartitions[_]]).
      head.asInstanceOf[TestOutputStreamWithPartitions[V]]
    val output = outputStream.output

    try {
      // Start computation
      ssc.start()

      // Advance manual clock
      val clock = ssc.scheduler.clock.asInstanceOf[ManualClock]
      logInfo("Manual clock before advancing = " + clock.getTimeMillis())
      if (actuallyWait) {
        for (i <- 1 to numBatches) {
          logInfo("Actually waiting for " + batchDuration)
          clock.advance(batchDuration.milliseconds)
          Thread.sleep(batchDuration.milliseconds)
        }
      } else {
        clock.advance(numBatches * batchDuration.milliseconds)
      }
      logInfo("Manual clock after advancing = " + clock.getTimeMillis())

      // Wait until expected number of output items have been generated
      val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
      while (output.size < numExpectedOutput &&
        System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < maxWaitTimeMillis) {
        logInfo("output.size = " + output.size + ", numExpectedOutput = " + numExpectedOutput)
        ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(50)
      }
      val timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
      logInfo("Output generated in " + timeTaken + " milliseconds")
      output.foreach(x => logInfo("[" + x.mkString(",") + "]"))
      assert(timeTaken < maxWaitTimeMillis, "Operation timed out after " + timeTaken + " ms")
      assert(output.size === numExpectedOutput, "Unexpected number of outputs generated")

      Thread.sleep(100) // Give some time for the forgetting old RDDs to complete
    } finally {
      ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true)
    }
    output
  }

  /**
   * Verify whether the output values after running a DStream operation
   * is same as the expected output values, by comparing the output
   * collections either as lists (order matters) or sets (order does not matter)
   */
  def verifyOutput[V: ClassTag](
      output: Seq[Seq[V]],
      expectedOutput: Seq[Seq[V]],
      useSet: Boolean
    ) {
    logInfo("--------------------------------")
    logInfo("output.size = " + output.size)
    logInfo("output")
    output.foreach(x => logInfo("[" + x.mkString(",") + "]"))
    logInfo("expected output.size = " + expectedOutput.size)
    logInfo("expected output")
    expectedOutput.foreach(x => logInfo("[" + x.mkString(",") + "]"))
    logInfo("--------------------------------")

    // Match the output with the expected output
    for (i <- 0 until output.size) {
      if (useSet) {
        assert(
          output(i).toSet === expectedOutput(i).toSet,
          s"Set comparison failed\n" +
            s"Expected output (${expectedOutput.size} items):\n${expectedOutput.mkString("\n")}\n" +
            s"Generated output (${output.size} items): ${output.mkString("\n")}"
        )
      } else {
        assert(
          output(i).toList === expectedOutput(i).toList,
          s"Ordered list comparison failed\n" +
            s"Expected output (${expectedOutput.size} items):\n${expectedOutput.mkString("\n")}\n" +
            s"Generated output (${output.size} items): ${output.mkString("\n")}"
        )
      }
    }
    logInfo("Output verified successfully")
  }

  /**
   * Test unary DStream operation with a list of inputs, with number of
   * batches to run same as the number of expected output values
   */
  def testOperation[U: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](
      input: Seq[Seq[U]],
      operation: DStream[U] => DStream[V],
      expectedOutput: Seq[Seq[V]],
      useSet: Boolean = false
    ) {
    testOperation[U, V](input, operation, expectedOutput, -1, useSet)
  }

  /**
   * Test unary DStream operation with a list of inputs
   * @param input      Sequence of input collections
   * @param operation  Binary DStream operation to be applied to the 2 inputs
   * @param expectedOutput Sequence of expected output collections
   * @param numBatches Number of batches to run the operation for
   * @param useSet     Compare the output values with the expected output values
   *                   as sets (order matters) or as lists (order does not matter)
   */
  def testOperation[U: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](
      input: Seq[Seq[U]],
      operation: DStream[U] => DStream[V],
      expectedOutput: Seq[Seq[V]],
      numBatches: Int,
      useSet: Boolean
    ) {
    val numBatches_ = if (numBatches > 0) numBatches else expectedOutput.size
    withStreamingContext(setupStreams[U, V](input, operation)) { ssc =>
      val output = runStreams[V](ssc, numBatches_, expectedOutput.size)
      verifyOutput[V](output, expectedOutput, useSet)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Test binary DStream operation with two lists of inputs, with number of
   * batches to run same as the number of expected output values
   */
  def testOperation[U: ClassTag, V: ClassTag, W: ClassTag](
      input1: Seq[Seq[U]],
      input2: Seq[Seq[V]],
      operation: (DStream[U], DStream[V]) => DStream[W],
      expectedOutput: Seq[Seq[W]],
      useSet: Boolean
    ) {
    testOperation[U, V, W](input1, input2, operation, expectedOutput, -1, useSet)
  }

  /**
   * Test binary DStream operation with two lists of inputs
   * @param input1     First sequence of input collections
   * @param input2     Second sequence of input collections
   * @param operation  Binary DStream operation to be applied to the 2 inputs
   * @param expectedOutput Sequence of expected output collections
   * @param numBatches Number of batches to run the operation for
   * @param useSet     Compare the output values with the expected output values
   *                   as sets (order matters) or as lists (order does not matter)
   */
  def testOperation[U: ClassTag, V: ClassTag, W: ClassTag](
      input1: Seq[Seq[U]],
      input2: Seq[Seq[V]],
      operation: (DStream[U], DStream[V]) => DStream[W],
      expectedOutput: Seq[Seq[W]],
      numBatches: Int,
      useSet: Boolean
    ) {
    val numBatches_ = if (numBatches > 0) numBatches else expectedOutput.size
    withStreamingContext(setupStreams[U, V, W](input1, input2, operation)) { ssc =>
      val output = runStreams[W](ssc, numBatches_, expectedOutput.size)
      verifyOutput[W](output, expectedOutput, useSet)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

These are a few things that you should check -

1. Verify if you have resources available that you are specifying in spark-config
2. Do a search for **stop()** keyword in your codebase and check it should not be on sparkcontext
3. Spark has Spark-UI component where you can see what job ran, if it failed or succeeded, along with its log. That will tell you why is it failing.

Comment: I think that the point 2 is the right reason of the issue. I checked `TestSuiteBase` (see my Update) and it only specifies StreamingContext. I tried to add `sc.stop()`, but then I should pass `sc` as a parameter of the function `runStreams(...)` and I'm not sure that this is the right way. Could you please elaborate a little bit your answer on this point?

Comment: Based on your updated TestSuiteBase, I would suggest to test this out by just commenting places where it says stop. If it work fine then do it one by one. You should be able to figure it out which one might be a problem. Rest of the code look fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is only one `SparkSession` or `SparkContext` is allowed per JVM. Make sure to the instance being used is a singleton. For instance, wrap the singleton of `SparkSession` (or `SparkContext`) in an `SharedSparkSession` (or `SharedSparkContext`) object.

Answer (score 2):

For me it happened when I was using structured streaming and forgot to await the termination of my streaming query:

`query.awaitAnyTermination()`.

**Look at the last 2 lines of this code:**

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val streamingDataFrame = spark.readStream...

  val purchaseByCustomerPerDay = streamingDataFrame
    .selectExpr(
      "CustomerID",
      "(UnitPrice * Quantity) as total_cost",
      "InvoiceDate")
    .groupBy($"CustomerID", window($"InvoiceDate", "1 day"))
    .sum("total_cost")

  val query = purchaseByCustomerPerDay.writeStream
    .format("console")
    .queryName("customer_purchases_2")
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
    .start()

  query.awaitTermination() // this is a must
  spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination() // or do this, to await all queries
```

P.S. in non-structured streaming with `DStream`s, you also have to call `sparkStreamingContext.awaitTermination()`.

Comment: This solved my issue in a PySpark unit test where the spark context shut down. It's worth noting that `.awaitTermination()` is needed even when you use trigger type `once=True`.

Answer (score 1):

`Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext` it is consequence of some error which happend earlier. Look at the logs in `$SPARK_HOME$/logs` and `$SPARK_HOME$/work`.

Comment: I cannot find logs in the home directory of Spark. Do I need to execute my code with Logging?

Comment: ok. where did you find this: 16/04/27 10:40:17 WARN StreamingContext....?just look above (if you limited by terminal window then you can redirect it to file)

Comment: I am using IntellijIDEA. How to save logs to the file? It's quite obvious if I run a program from terminal (> log), but what should I do in case of IntellijIDEA? Sorry for beginner's questions...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736020/is-it-possible-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-log-file-in-intellij-like-eclipse anyway you can try to run it from terminal. and again. you sure that there are no logs in 'logs' and 'work' directory?

Comment: Ok, it says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext` and points to the last line of the code `val gridEvalsRDD = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(gridEvals)`. Nothing else is mentioned on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the spark context on interpreter binding panel worked for me it looks like something bellow you just have to click on the refresh button and save.
[image]