# [Zeppelin]Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext

Tags: apache-zeppelin

**When we use spark through zeppelin spark interpreter in share per note model, sometimes we get the following error info:**

```
WARN [2019-11-11 13:37:29,610] ({pool-2-thread-16} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2302) - Job 20191028-172705_1731645157 is finished, status: ERROR, exception: null, result: %text java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.spark2CreateContext(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:233)
org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.createSparkContext(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:165)
org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala211Interpreter.open(SparkScala211Interpreter.scala:87)
org.apache.zeppelin.spark.NewSparkInterpreter.open(NewSparkInterpreter.java:102)
org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:62)
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:617)
org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

(No active SparkContext.
```

**we have reproduce this error info by the following steps:**

1. create two notes, one is note A, the other is note B
2. for note A and B, run some paragraghs and see all succeeded
3. now, delete note A and then we run next paragragh in B, then the error happened

How can we solve this problem? is this a issue of zeppelin spark interpreter itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884845/cannot-call-methods-on-a-stopped-sparkcontext)

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same error message. From your description above I realized that I was running two Zeppelin instances with the same interpreter which were pointing to the same data sources (but different notebooks). On my side, I solved the issue by closing the second Zeppelin instance, and restarting my interpret.

I would suggest that you investigate the configs of your interpreter, being global or per user, to see if that may not be the cause of the problem.