# How to see a particular metric in Spark Structured Streaming with Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm very new to Spark and Python. I'm trying to see any metric in Spark Structured Streaming (for example, `processedRowsPerSecond`), but I don't know how to do it.

I've read in "*Structured Streaming Programming Guide*" that with `print(query.lastProgress)` you can directly get the current status and metrics of an active query, but if I write it I only obtain `None` once. The last part of my code is the following:

```
query = windowedCountsDF\
    .writeStream\
    .outputMode('update')\
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .format('console') \
    .queryName("numbers") \
    .start()

print(query.lastProgress)

query.awaitTermination()
```

Any idea on how to do it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
while query.isActive:
    print("\n")
    print(query.status)
    print(query.lastProgress)
    time.sleep(30)
```

`query.awaitTermination()` blocks `query.lastProgress`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Alex. Only one more question: if I want to access to a particular metric in lastProgress (I think lastProgress is a dictionary), what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on what do you want to do with that metric.  Your problem is that you're calling `query.awaitTermination()`, and it blocks any other activity.  If you want to collect metrics, then instead of calling `query.awaitTermination()`, you need to implement your own wait loop, something like this:

```
query = ...

while not query.exception():
  if query.lastProgress:
    print(query.lastProgress) # do something with your data
  time.sleep(10) # wait 10 seconds..
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I've have implemented your code, but I get the following error message: File "numbers.py", line 42, in <module>
    recentProgress = query.recentProgress()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
21/12/18 14:07:32 ERROR streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query numbers [id = ee2bc067-90c4-4d91-9c5b-dc00388f68b4, runId = 619509e1-4e81-4a78-a553-d75d6c0521a7] terminated with error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.

Comment: sorry, it was an error in the code, just copied a piece from documentation, forgot that it's a member of the class, not function. It's also better to use `lastProgress` function.

Comment: Sorry Alex, but it still doesn't work. I get this error message: 21/12/18 15:56:07 ERROR streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query numbers [id = 0edfdfa9-5cb0-4373-99b7-1a931d6883e0, runId = 83002c13-1260-4317-8043-a025820a514f] terminated with error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884845/cannot-call-methods-on-a-stopped-sparkcontext