# AWS Glue error: Writing a Dataframe to table with large data throwing spark memory error

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, parquet

I am trying to read parquet files(80 files in total) from the landing S3 bucket and trying to create an Iceberg table in the raw bucket.

I can create a dataframe with landing files while writing into a table getting the below errors:

- `ERROR:root:An error occurred while calling o748.defaultParallelism. : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext. This stopped SparkContext was created at:`

[image]

- `Write failed with error: An error occurred while calling o743.create:org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted`

[image]

- `Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 31 in stage 43.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 31.3 in stage 43.0 (TID 528) (10.236.38.189 executor 19): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 19 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages. Driver stacktrace:`

[image]

1. I have tried to increase the number of workers still not working.
2. Have tried the repartition.
3. Even taking a count from the Dataframe throws the same error.
4. We have 200 tables. The same script works for all the other bigger tables but fails for 1 table.

**Reading part in script:**

```py
s3_src_landing_ddf = self.glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            format_options={},
            connection_type="s3",
            format="parquet",
            connection_options={
                "paths": [s3_file_list],
                "recurse": recurse_val
            },
            transformation_ctx="s3_src_landing_ddf",
        )
```

**Writing part:**

```py
s3_src_landing_df.writeTo("glue_catalog."+schema_nm+"." + table.lower()).tableProperty(
                    "format-version", "2"
                ).tableProperty(
                    "location", "s3://raw_bucket/source_system/db_name+/table.lower()"
                ).create()
```

**`count()` also throws same error:**

```py
s3_src_landing_df.count()
```

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884845/cannot-call-methods-on-a-stopped-sparkcontext) for the `stopped SparkContext` error.

Comment: That is not working