# How to redirect console output to text file in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

i wanted to redirect console output to a text file as in eclipse we can redirect it to some text file can we also do it in inteeliJ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to redirect console output to a log file in IntelliJ like Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736020/is-it-possible-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-log-file-in-intellij-like-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do this. When you run the main class in IDE, there will be an option for edit configurations something like the image below:

[image: Edit configurations]

Click on the edit configurations option. Now, **Navigate to the Logs tab and redirect the output** in the file as shown below.

[image: save-log-file]

Click on the Apply button. Now your application log would start coming in the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can this work for gradle project? i tried the steps which you mentioned but that dint work

Comment: This configuration works for gradle as well. If your project is able to produce some output to the console then it would  redirect to the file as well.

Comment: i tried still its not working. Which version intellij you use?